# How can I turn NSData's hex string into a normal hex string?

Tags: objective-c, hex

So, take an unsigned int, say 4286578687.

From this site: http://www.mathsisfun.com/binary-decimal-hexadecimal-converter.html

I get the hex value to be: FF7FFFFF

However, if I put that int into NSData like so:

```
//The unsigned int is unsignedInt and its length is unsignedLength 

NSData *thisData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&unsignedInt length:unsignedLength];
```

And then use the description method, which supposedly returns the data's hex value as a string:

```
NSLog(@"data as hex: %@", [thisData description]);
```

The output is:

```
data as hex: <ffff7fff>
```

Which on the same website evaluates to 4294934527.

So it seems like NSData is using some non-standard hex format. Can anyone tell me how to get back to the real hex format?

Comment: It's the difference between big-endian and little-endian.

Comment: Note: You don't have to call `description`. It's called implicitly in logs.

Comment: Why do you care? You should not be relying on anything about the way `NSData`'s description is formatted.

Comment: I need to convert the data into an exact representation of its bit sequence. Read please: *bit* (I've gotten in trouble because people thought I was saying byte). I've found a hex-to-bit routine here on SO, but it only works if the hex going in is the same as the hex coming out.

Comment: Then you need to access the `-bytes` of the `NSData`, not its description. Or just the bytes of the `unsignedInt` as in `(const char*)&unsignedInt`. Looking at the `NSData`'s description is just going to make the work harder and cause trouble.

Comment: It's really six of one, a half-dozen of the other. If accessing the raw bytes, I have to read a bit at a time and account for endianness as I reassemble them. If using the hex string, I have to convert it to the opposite endianness and then get a binary representation of that. The thing I think you might think is clear, but isn't (to me at least) is why it should not be done through the description. You say it very definitely, so I wonder if I'm missing something fundamental. Is it that the description is not guaranteed to be in any given format, so updates to objective C could break it?

Comment: Yes, the description is not guaranteed to be in any given format. In general, all Cocoa `-description` methods are for human consumption for diagnostic purposes and are not reliable for computer parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing a difference between storing the bytes of the `unsigned int` in big-endian versus little-endian.

If you want to guarantee that the output of the `NSData` is in big-endian format then you should do the following:

```
unsigned int x = 4286578687;
unsigned int big = NSSwapHostIntToBig(x);
NSData *thisData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&big length:sizeof(big)];
NSLog(@"data as hex: %@", thisData);
```

This logs the expected result of `data as hex: <ff7fffff>`.

This code will work on any processor type and always give you the result in big-endian format.

When going back the other way you would need to use the `NSSwapBigIntToHost` function to ensure the big-endian data is properly converted to the local format.

Comment: As far as I know, the ARM processor on the iOS devices runs in little-endian mode, and thus has the same endianness as the Simulator on OS X.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, you are correct. I don't know why I was thinking that. I've removed that part of my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy - thanks so much. All the big-vs-little is a bit confusing, let's say I am *starting* with the (incorrect) hex value. What I need to do is take the NSData hex value -- which is wrong -- and turn it into either (a) the right hex value or (b) the right integer. Maybe I should be able to get this from your example, but it seems to be in the opposite order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
NSInteger i = 4286578687;
NSLog(@"hex : %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%X", i]);

// Result
>>> hex : FF7FFFFF
```